# Why list size shows zero?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have used spring boot, try to retrieve all the product from the database ( MySQL ) . But list size is zero. There is no error is shown to console.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showListOfProduct", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showList(Model model) {       
    List<Products> allProduct = productService.listAllProducts();
    System.out.println("sizeEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"+ allProduct.size());
    model.addAttribute("allProduct", allProduct);
    return "showlist";
}
```

This is repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {

}
```

This is service:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public List<Products> listAllProducts() {
    return productRepository.findAll();
}
```

This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="productname")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name="numberofavailableinstock")
    private long  numberofavailableInStock;

    @Column(name="productprice")
    private String productPrice;

    @Column(name="percentageofsell")
    private double percentageOfSell;
// setter getter
```

This is my application.properties:

```
> spring.mvc.view.prefix: webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/ spring.mvc.view.suffix:
> .jsp server.port=7000 spring.datasource.url=
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproduct spring.datasource.username=root
> spring.datasource.password=root
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

My database is:

```
> Table: products Columns: id int(11) AI PK  productname varchar(45) 
> productprice varchar(45)  numberofavailableinstock varchar(45) 
> percentageofsell varchar
```

Comment: What does your log says? Run your boot app in debug mode to know more about the query as well. Do you have Products (if not overriden in your entity class) table?

Comment: Yes, There are have some data in database. And I have added entity in post.

Comment: you can enable jpa log `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to see the query which is executed. You can run this query against your db to see if there is an issue.

Comment: @Patrick - select products0_.id as id1_0_, products0_.numberofavailableinstock as numberof2_0_, products0_.percentageofsell as percenta3_0_, products0_.productname as productn4_0_, products0_.productprice as productp5_0_ from products products0_ , this is the query

Comment: run this query against your db. Do you get any results then?

Comment: @Patrick- list  is 0.what should I do now?

Comment: Please add your DB schema and your Products @Entity to your example.

Comment: @DaShaun - I have added.Check this

Comment: @OUNAsh percentageofsell varchar ?  Schema and Entity don't match.

Comment: @DaShaun- Thanks.I changed it. But it didn't work.

Comment: @OUNAsh did you also update numberofavailableinstock varchar? should be long?

Comment: @OUNAsh you should take a look at adding these to your  application.properties:

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163659/discussion-between-dashaun-and-oun-ash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I run into this type of issue, its because my @Entity and the schema don't match up properly.

You should consider adding these two properties to your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

That will help you keep schema and entity matching.